# Skip the block in CI/CD pipeline of Semaphore when there is changes only in docs directory (Semaphore)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, devops, semaphore, cicd

At the moment, we go through the full CI/CD process for changes to documentation ( eg in the project /docs folder).

This makes it a bit more difficult for people to make changes to docs, as each change triggers CI/CD workflows, redeploys the latest version of the app to staging/production etc - all of which is unnecessary.

I want to amend the semaphore.yml so that none of our CI/CD steps runs when the only changes in a commit are in the /docs directory.

I tried the solution mentioned here ( [CI/CD](https://docs.semaphoreci.com/reference/conditions-reference/#when-a-directory-changes)) but it doesn' work.

```
blocks:
  - name: Linting
    dependencies: []
    run:
      when: "change_in('/', {exclude: ['/docs']})"
    task:
      agent:
        machine:
          type: e1-standard
          os_image: ubuntu
        containers:
```

Comment: According to the documentation your condition appears appropriate assuming that the change is actually made in '/docs' and nowhere else. That being said it would likely be easier and more flexible to use a git tag like 'skip-ci' to manage this.

Comment: @engineersmnkyThank you. do you think is there any other way we can handle through `semaphore.yml` configuration

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually doing so I can't say. If you are only changing files in the /docs directory then what you have should work. Otherwise you will need to find a means that suits your needs. Semaphore can read the git tags and act or not act according to the tag which is why I suggested doing it that way.

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah I am trying to change only /docs directory file but it doesn't    skip the block which I am expecting with the above change `run:
      when: "change_in('/', {exclude: ['/docs']})"`  instead it runs all blocks of ci/cd pipeline.